# RTL and LTR Drawer Navigation switching between them depending on user language

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-redux, react-navigation

How to add drawer dynamic drawer navigation that changes from RTL to ltr and vice versa.
after logged in goes to the main page where drawer be able to open but its position depending on the language that user chose it when logged in

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
    import TeaApp from './Pages/navigation';


    export default class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
          name : '',
        };

      }

      render() {
        return (

            <TeaApp/>

        );
      }
    }
```

**navigation**

```
            import React,{ Component } from 'react';
            import { AsyncStorage, View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, Button, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
            import { StackNavigator , SwitchNavigator, DrawerNavigator, DrawerItems,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-navigation';
            import Login from './login';
            import Mainpage from './mainPage';
            import Menu from './menu';
            import CustomizeOrder from './customizeOrder';
            import Intro from './intro';
            import PreviewOrder from './previewOrder';
            import ViewOrder from './viewOrder';

            const INTRO = StackNavigator({ Intro:{screen: Intro} });
            const LOGIN = StackNavigator({ Login:{screen: Login} });

            const REST = StackNavigator({ 
                UserHome:{screen: Mainpage,navigationOptions:({navigation})=>({drawerLockMode:"locked-closed"})},
                Menu:{screen: Menu,navigationOptions:({navigation})=>({drawerLockMode:"locked-closed"})},
                customizeOrder:{screen: CustomizeOrder,navigationOptions:({navigation})=>({drawerLockMode:"locked-closed"})},
                previewOrder:{screen: PreviewOrder,navigationOptions:({navigation})=>({drawerLockMode:"locked-closed"})}, 
                viewOrder:{screen: ViewOrder,navigationOptions:({navigation})=>({drawerLockMode:"locked-closed"})}, 

            });


            const DrawerUserAR = DrawerNavigator(
                {
                    الصفحة_الرئيسية :{screen: REST,navigationOptions:({navigation})=>({drawerLockMode:"locked-closed"})},
                    المطبخ :{screen: KitchenPage},
                    الطلبات:{screen: VIEWORDER},
                    تغيير_كلمة_المرور:{screen: ChangePassword},
                    تغيير_اللغة: {screen: ChangeLanguage}
                    //logout:{}
                },
                {
                    initialRouteName: 'الصفحة_الرئيسية',
                    drawerPosition: 'right',
                    contentComponent:(props) => (
                        <View style={{flex:1}}>
                            <Image
                                style={styles.drawerImage}
                                source={{uri:props.descriptors.الصفحة_الرئيسية.navigation.state.routes[0].params.content.company_logo_small}} />
                            <Text/>
                            <Text style={{textAlign:'center',fontSize:15,marginVertical:15}}>{props.descriptors.الصفحة_الرئيسية.navigation.state.routes[0].params.content.name}</Text>
                            <Text/>
                            <DrawerItems {...props} />
                            <Text/><Text/>
                            <Text/><Text/>
                            <Text/><Text/>
                            <Text/><Text/>
                            <Text/><Text/>
                        </View>),
                    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
                    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
                    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
                }
            );

            const DrawerUserEN = DrawerNavigator(
                {
                    Mainpage :{screen: REST,navigationOptions:({navigation})=>({drawerLockMode:"locked-closed"})},
                    Kitchen :{screen: KitchenPage},
                    viewOrder:{screen: VIEWORDER},
                    changePassword:{screen: ChangePassword},
                    changeLanguage: {screen: ChangeLanguage}
                    //logout:{}
                },
                {
                    initialRouteName: 'Mainpage',
                    drawerPosition: 'left',
                    contentComponent:(props) => 
                        (
                        <View style={{flex:1}}>
                            <Image
                                style={styles.drawerImage}
                                source={{uri:props.descriptors.Mainpage.navigation.state.routes[0].params.content.company_logo_small}} />
                            <Text/>
                            <Text style={{textAlign:'center',fontSize:15,marginVertical:15}}>{props.descriptors.Mainpage.navigation.state.routes[0].params.content.name}</Text>
                            <Text/>
                            <DrawerItems {...props} />
                            <Text/><Text/>
                            <Text/><Text/>
                            <Text/><Text/>

                        </View>),
                    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
                    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
                    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
                }
            );

            export default SwitchNavigator(
                {
                    intro:{screen: INTRO},
                    login:{screen: LOGIN},
                    rest:{screen: REST},
                    rest:{screen: /*drawer depending on the language that will get it from login*/},
                },
                {
                    initialRouteName: 'intro'
                }
            );


            const styles = StyleSheet.create({

                container: {
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center'
                },
                drawerHeader: {
                height: 200,
                backgroundColor: 'white'
                },
                drawerImage: {
                marginTop: 20,
                height: 150,
                width: 150,
                borderRadius: 75,
                alignSelf:'center'
                }

            })
```

________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________                                     ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

Comment: Please use code to show your current setup and what you've researched and tried so far

Comment: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3504 - brentvatne (one of the developers) said you cannot do this (this was in February). The only alternative I can think of is to make two drawers - one for left side and one for right side, and navigate to the appropriate one depending on your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this issue by I18nManager! It's working great. I have 2 buttons in my app that each of them indicates a specific language, one of them is Persian that needs the app to become RTL and one of them is English which needs to be LTR. whenever a user presses each of these buttons, below function will be called:

```
 import {I18nManager} from 'react-native'
 import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart';

 async changeAppLang(lang) {

    if(lang == 'fa') {
        if (!I18nManager.isRTL) {
            await I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
          }
    } else {
        if (I18nManager.isRTL) {
            await I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
          }
    }
    RNRestart.Restart()
}
```

the RNRestart package is for restarting application and you should install it using the command below:

```
npm install react-native-restart --save
react-native link react-native-restart
```

the "lang" argument is a string that I pass to this function whenever one of the language buttons is pressed. for example I pass "fa" when persian button is pressed, I pass 'en' when English button is pressed. so with the code above, I change `I18nManager.isRTL` state. I then edited drawer position like below:

```
import {I18nManager} from 'react-native';
const drawer = createDrawerNavigator({
  Main: Main
}, {
     drawerPosition: I18nManager.isRTL ?'right':'left',
     contentComponent: DrawerMenu
})
```

hope it help anyone looking for an answer.

Comment: Could you please explain it more, I'm still waiting for you